# call logging in j2me

Tags: java, java-me, call

I want to make call log in j2me. I had tried [this](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/J2ME_API_Bridge_Interface) wiki information. But it make my device hang.
And i had found [this](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/MIDP_2.0_API_access_rights) wiki information.
Can any one please that is it possible call logging in j2me.
If yes how is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible through j2me. Yet no API is available for it. You can do in symbian c++.

Comment: But i had found this link from nokia forum--http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/J2ME_Api_Bridge_Interface.I had tried to use bridgeapi.But it is giving me bridge exception.Please Help me.